# Google Analytics 4 showing all traffic is "Direct"

Tags: google-analytics, google-search-console, google-analytics-4

1 week after setting up a new site with Google Analytics 4, GA stopped showing any search engine traffic information and now shows all traffic as Direct

[image: https://imgur.com/a/kePQl8E]

I'm stumped as to why GA is losing all referrer information. I've ensured the site pages being indexed are the HTTPS version so browsers don't drop the referrer headers. The site is getting a handful of clicks every day from both Bing and Google as well as several direct linking sites. Despite the diversity of incoming traffic, all recent traffic is only listed as "Direct".

[image]

Any suggestions for diagnosing?

Comment: We have gotten a fair number of questions from folks asking about problems or missing features in GA4.  It doesn't look to me like it is ready for prime time yet.   I'd recommend sticking with universal analytics for the time being.

Comment: Around the 21st quite a few people reported this sort of error. I'm also seeing it. What @StephenOstermiller said.